# Making borders for bottom\left on the inside of an element, none for top\rigth

Tags: html, css

I need to create a **DIV** with borders on the inside.
However, I only need borders on the **bottom** and **left** sides, like so:

```
 +++++++++
 +|      +
 +|      +
 +|      +
 +|______+
 +++++++++

+ : DIV's boundary
| : border
```

Some solutions I've seen here that won't work:

- `box-sizing`, because I need the right and top borders to be clear.
- `box-shadow`, because I need it to be inside the div.
- `border-left` \ `border-bottom`, because it won't be on the inside of my DIV.

Should I just set a border for the left and bottom sides and then set an appropriate margin of **BORDER_WIDTH**, or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks.

p.s. pure CSS solution required.

Comment: box-shadow has an "inset" property: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Comment: Show me your HTML structure, please.

Comment: Why doesn't this http://jsfiddle.net/CdTKd/3/ follow your requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`box-shadow` has an "[inset](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow)" property: so you can use this style

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  box-shadow: 10px -10px 0 0 #000 inset; /* use vendor prefixes if necessary */
}
```

Of course adjust the offset and/or the colour of the shadow as you need.
Example on codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LoFvj

---

Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, use the box-shadow to create the outside border

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/HgbJj)

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 4px red solid;
  border-top:none;
  border-right:none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0 0 1px grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pseudo selectors to give the illusion of an inside border.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kt9hq/1/)

```
.inner-border {
   border-left: 5px solid #000;
   border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
   border-right: 5px solid red;
   border-top: 5px solid red;
   position: relative;    
}

.inner-border:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: -10px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```